# What is the preference for Java compilers regarding order of classes?

Tags: java

Do certain Java compilers prefer a different layout of a Java file before it is compiled unto a class file for the JVM?

What I mean is, by first writing your main Class and then writing all your other classes in the following lines bring or not a faster compile time?

Does the compiler take longer because it has not yet encountered what it is it needs for the relevant information in the main Class?

If I recall correctly, Java doesn't use explicit pointers either so I don't see that being an issue.

In other words, if you write your Classes outside of main first does this speed up compile time?

Comment: When you compile, all the sources are already written. So the order in which they were written is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean ?  Are you referring to compilation into Java byte code by the JRE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple: you specify the order of classes.

In other words: you give a list of file or directory names to the compiler. And then the compiler processes those in the order given, to then walk through each file. Sometimes it will make forward reference to understand that types are used that aren't defined yet.

I *guess*: when you ask the compiler to go for a complete directory, it will simply read the files in the order that the file system uses (like alphabetical).

Finally: this is definitely an implementation detail of the compiler (or even the build tool that generates the commands running the compiler). So a different tool, or tool version might lead to different results. So again: don't waste your time to "optimize" for this.

Comment: You don't have to specify all classes to be compiled. Depending on type of app, you might only need to specify the main class, and all other classes will be compiled too, simply because the are referenced directly or indirectly from the main class. I'm referring to manual `javac` command-line compilation. With IDE or build script (Maven, Ant, Gradle, ...) compilation, you don't control the order of files given to the compiler, because there you just say "everything below this directory".

Comment: Forward references and order specification mean a great deal.   I have never used a compiler.  I have used an interpreter a few times in a class maybe 9 years ago.  I am learning about the mechanics of programming without the need to put it into practice.  It has worked so far, and I know it will continue to work.  I really appreciate your answer. =)

Comment: I never knew about javac command line compilation.  Thanks Andreas.

Comment: I guess the compiler probably gives you more function then a button that says compile.  Something I never realized.  Though I do know about switches for the C programming language.  Or flags.

Answer (score 6):

If any such difference exists, it would be so negligible you won't notice it.

In other words - you should focus on organizing the classes in a way that would make sense and would be easy for you to maintain, not on helping the compiler.

Comment: I know that already, I know that is why people write them before or after but I am interested in the compiler aspect which is why I asked how I did.  I am curious about the Java compilers.

Comment: You put "faster compile" into your question, so don't be surprised when people tell you that you are going down a very wrong rabbit hole by organizing code to enhance compile times. It is 2018. Even a mediocre laptop can easily compile hundreds of classes within seconds.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my erroneous thinking, but I still would like to know about these bench marks.  Are there ways of going about achieving benchmarks?  Is this going to lead unto a more hardware focus methodology or is it going to lead unto a focus on the compiler mechanics and intricacies ?